# Ruby On Rails XML to View

Tags: model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3, google-api, google-docs-api

I have a controller with an API request showing all my Google Docs.

feed = client.get('http://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full').to_xml

```
    feed.elements.each('entry') do |entry|
      puts 'title: ' + entry.elements['title'].text
      puts 'type: ' + entry.elements['category'].attribute('label').value
      puts 'updated: ' + entry.elements['updated'].text
      puts 'id: ' + entry.elements['id'].text

      # Extract the href value from each <atom:link>
      links = {}
      entry.elements.each('link') do |link|
        links[link.attribute('rel').value] = link.attribute('href').value
      end
      puts links.to_s
```

end

So, I can see the results in my console but how do I get them into my view?

I tried with something like this, but that doesn't work (I changed my variable in the controller to an accessor of course)

> <% feed.elements.each('entry') do
>   |entry| %>        <%
>   entry.elements['title'].text %>   <%
>   end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Because I use 'puts' in the controller to show the content of the feed in the console I also have to change that for the view. Of course, puts is equal to <%= ... %>.

```
<ul>
    <% @feed.elements.each('entry') do |entry| %>
        <li><%= 'title: ' + entry.elements['title'].text %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in your controller, make feed an instance variable. IE: it should be:

`@feed = client.get.....` instead of `feed = client.get....`

If that doesn't fix it... I don't know your API for sure, but I suspect you may need to be using:

`<% @feed.elements.each('entry') do |entry| %> <% entry['title'] %> <% end %>`

Note: `entry['title']` instead of `entry.elements['title'].text`

What your current code indicates is that the feed is structured like this:

`feed.elements[0].elements['attr'].text`, when it's probably just `feed.elements[0]['attr']`

Does that make sense? Try that and see what happens.

If that doesn't work, just put: `debug(@feed)` in your view and copy and paste it to the end of your question. That'll help us figure out the right way to access this info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got some more knowledge about accessors an Ruby syntax with your tips and solved my problem (take a look at my answer).